# Exception not being catched

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, exception

In my MVC 5 application, I have this code:

```
try
{
    var inputFile = new MediaFile { Filename = videoPath };
    var outputFile = new MediaFile { Filename = Config.ThumbPath };

    using (var engine = new Engine())
    {
        engine.GetMetadata(inputFile);

        if (inputFile.Metadata != null && inputFile.Metadata.Duration.TotalSeconds > 0)
        {
            var options = new ConversionOptions { Seek = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(inputFile.Metadata.Duration.TotalSeconds / 2) };
            engine.GetThumbnail(inputFile, outputFile, options);

            byte[] imageArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Config.ThumbPath);
            base64ImageRepresentation = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(imageArray);
        }
    }

}
catch (Exception ex)
{ 
     if (!EventLog.SourceExists("MYAPP"))
           EventLog.CreateEventSource("MYAPP", "Application");

     EventLog.WriteEntry("MYAPP", "CACHED: " + ex.Message);
     EventLog.WriteEntry("MYAPP", "CACHED: " + ex.Message,EventLogEntryType.Warning,234);
}
```

Line `engine.GetMetadata(inputFile);` throws this:

> > An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

It's in a library called MediaToolkit which I installed from NuGet.

Why does my try catch doesnt catch this exception?

The file it gets is corrupt and thats why it throws the error, but if that happens I just want to continue to the next file. But, instead, the application stops.

There is no entry in event log for this, but there is another entry for source ASP.NET.

```
An unhandled exception occurred and the process was terminated.

Application ID: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT

Process ID: 7364

Exception: System.FormatException

Message: Input string was not in a correct format.

StackTrace:    at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.Convert.ToInt32(String value)
   at MediaToolkit.Util.RegexEngine.TestAudio(String data, EngineParameters engine)
   at MediaToolkit.Engine.<>c__DisplayClass9.<FFmpegEngine>b__5(Object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs received)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.ErrorReadNotifyUser(String data)
   at System.Diagnostics.AsyncStreamReader.FlushMessageQueue()
   at System.Diagnostics.AsyncStreamReader.GetLinesFromStringBuilder()
   at System.Diagnostics.AsyncStreamReader.ReadBuffer(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.IO.Stream.ReadWriteTask.InvokeAsyncCallback(Object completedTask)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.IO.Stream.ReadWriteTask.System.Threading.Tasks.ITaskCompletionAction.Invoke(Task completingTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageThree()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageTwo()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Finish(Boolean bUserDelegateExecuted)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(Boolean bPreventDoubleExecution)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

Comment: Please try to add some logging to verify if the application enters `catch` block after the exception is thrown and before it stops.

Comment: I have something similar happening.  My guess is that the exception is being thrown in a separate thread by the AsynStreamReader.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your **Visual Studio is configured to stop execution on each generated exception** (even handled). You can check it in Debug -> Exceptions. Check **Common Language Runtime Exceptions** category, **Thrown** setting. If this setting is checked, VS will stop execution on each generated CLR Exception, you can just press F5 to continue or turn off this setting.

For more info, visit [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh.aspx).

Comment: No, that option is not checked in my vs.

Comment: A Visual Studio setting is not going to help catch an unhanded when the app is running from IIS.